# Line breaking inside BIG parenthesis

Tags: equations, amsmath, line-breaking, brackets, braces

[image: expected output]

I tried line break as well as \newline command inside parentheses but it did not work.

Comment: Can you show us your attempt? A complete minimal example helps. Also, does the image show what you want to have or your try?

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
    Z_{ij} =
    \left\{
        \begin{aligned}
            |Y_{ij}-\overline{Y_i}|&, \text{ $\overline{Y_i}$ is the mean of the $i$\textsuperscript{th} group}\\
            |Y_{ij}-\widetilde{Y_i}|&, \text{ $\widetilde{Y_i}$ is the median of the $i$\textsuperscript{th} group}
        \end{aligned}
    \right\}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility: using the `Bmatrix*` environment from `mathtools`, which can have an optional argument to set the alignment in the matrix (it is centred by default):

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{mathtools}

    \begin{document}

    \[
        Z_{ij} =
            \begin{Bmatrix*}[l]
                |Y_{ij}-\overline{Y_i}|, \enspace \overline{Y_i} \textup{ is the mean of the $i^{\text{th}}$ group}\\
                |Y_{ij}-\widetilde{Y_i}|,\enspace \widetilde{Y_i} \textup{ is the median of the $i^{\textup{th}}$ group}
            \end{Bmatrix*}
    \]

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Using the unstarred `Bmatrix` (`amsmath`) centers the two lines, which is how they're shown in the question.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: You're right, but I find it looks better when it is left-aligned – that's why I proposed this version.

Comment: Actually, I agree about the appearance, just observing (obliquely) that maybe that observation might have been made more clearly in your answer.  (Eternal pedant here.  In the question, I could also have observed that the verts should really all be the same size, but they're not, and also that the text is set as math, not `\text`; you might want to consider `\textup`.  I did upvote.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I don't understand – the text itself is upright, I only maintained math mode for what can be considered as formulæ inside the braces.

Comment: If the main text surrounding this element is upright, `\text` will bu upright.  But if it's embedded in an italic theorem, `\text` will behave like `\textit`.  Surprises a lot of people.

Comment: Oh! I didn't think of this possibility!

Comment: Fixed. Thank you, milady!

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `alignedat` and no `\left` and `\right` like in the shown picture (as you see, the bars are oversized).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
Z_{ij}=
\left\{
\begin{alignedat}{2}
&\bigl|Y_{ij}-\bar{Y}_{i}\bigr|,   &\quad&
  \text{$\bar{Y}_{i}$ is the mean of the $i$th group} \\
&\bigl|Y_{ij}-\tilde{Y}_{i}\bigr|, &     &
  \text{$\tilde{Y}_{i}$ is the median of the $i$th group}
\end{alignedat}
\right\}
\]

\end{document}
```

Note also `\text`. Please, avoid the “superscript th”. It's a relic of Victorian age typography that was somehow revived by the preferences of some developers of an unfortunately well-known word processing program.

[image]

The picture you show at least correctly uses `\bar` and `\tilde`. There is no need for `\overline` (that does a bad job) or `\widetilde`.